# how i make custom template in Drupal 7

Tags: templates, drupal

I am new on drupal, Can you help me to make custom template in drupal and how i call this?

I want to create a custom template and how i call this in my node
and also please describe how the block call in under page content, there is any shortcode for block?

Answer (score 0):

Hi create **YouThemeName** folder and put it in /site/all/themes/.
In theme folder create file YouThemeName.info and insert it:

```
name = YouThemeName
description = YouThemeDescription.
package = Core
version = VERSION
core = 7.x
// Regions 
regions[header] = Header
regions[content] = Content
regions[footer] = Footer
```

And you new template is ready. For more inforamation please visit Drupal.org and [read documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to override some Drupal template? As of Drupal 7.33 there is theme debug mode, to enable just add row to your settings.php: $conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE; and then just open page for which you want to override template and open developer tools there(Use Ctrl+Shift+I (or Cmd+Opt+I on Mac)), you will see something like this http://take.ms/XOXZt and can identify which template to create and how to call it, more you can read here https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom template in drupal is super easy, you can create a file name like `node--[type|nodeid].tpl.php` and place it in templates folder of your theme.
Remaining drupal does the magic, your can do your stuffs in the custom template file. Similar way to create for custom block tempalte file too.
For more information you can check this url:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656